# Rebase branch after moving to monorepo

Tags: javascript, git, github, version-control

Our GitHub OSS project was recently changed to a monorepo. As a consequence, the directory structure changed and a new folder has been created for the part I had written.

I wanted to rebase my branch onto this new monorepo, into the right folder. I tried a couple of times, but messed up.

So, before, the folder structure was:

> root-directory-for-my-part/...(src etc.)

Now, it is:

> monorepo-directory/root-directory-for-my-part/...(src etc.)

Another contributor set up that monorepo. How do I rebase my code into the right folder there?

I am using *git* and *GitHub*. My branch is called `custom-insertion-point`. The remote repo branch is `@next`. I have added the original remote repo to my git as `upstream` and my own fork as `origin`.

---

**NOTE:**

I already made the PR for my part previously (the code is done). I just need to rebase it onto the new monorepo.

I tried to follow this guide without success: https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/How-to-Rebase-a-Pull-Request

---

**UPDATE:**

So far I have done:

1. `git merge-base my-branch upstream/next` and copied the commit hash
2. `git rebase -i ${HASH}` using the commit hash above
3. Squashed the commits (as indicated in the guide linked above)
4. `git log` seems to report that there is now indeed just one commit on my `custom-insertion-point` branch

I guess that is correct so far. Now I somehow need to rebase that squashed commit onto the new monorepo, but in the right subfolder.

I tried to just do:

`git rebase upstream/next`

That caused a bunch of conflicts and my entire local working tree was changed to replicate the monorepo (but without my own code)...

---

**UPDATE2:**

I tried the following command again:

`git rebase upstream/next`

The issue is that everything ends up in the wrong folder. New files I created for my part end up in the root of the monorepo. Other files that was there before my part, but that I modified for my part, end up in the correct subfolder.

Comment: Prior to you current branch, did any files exist in the `root-directory-for-my-part` folder that were checked into version control?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Everything was checked in and the PR was waiting to be merged. Before it was merged, we decided to move to a monorepo.

Answer (score 1):

You should work merges rather than rebase, because really, it's a merge.
Also there a nice github help page for [Git subtree merges](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-git-subtree-merges) which is mostly what you are trying to achieve.

Also, it's worth to note that git has a contrib which is called `subtree`.
You can have a look at `git subtree` output / docs.

Comment: Thanks. We actually wanted a rebase though. To move my commit history onto the new version of next (not to merge the two).

Comment: ok, sorry, I don't answered the question ;). I wonder why you prefer a rebase, with a merge, you create a (merge) commit onto the new version of next, which inlude your history as-is.

Comment: @Magnus What is the reason that you prefer a rebase here?

Comment: Someone more experienced with git than myself asked for it. I am guessing the reason is that with rebase we can read the history of the next branch as if we all just worked linearly on that. E.g. the normal reasons for rebase I guess..

Comment: What do you mean by "linearly" ?

Comment: Also, as GitHub says in the article I linked in OP: "Regardless of the reason, if your pull request has gone stale, you will need to rebase your branch onto the latest version of the master branch before it can be merged." See: https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/How-to-Rebase-a-Pull-Request

Comment: @user801247 By linearly, I was thinking about the merge commits. Instead of having one merge commit in the git log history of `next`, we now see all the work I did on `custom-insertion-point`. It is easier to look back at the git commit history with rebase. It basically moves the entire `custom-insertion-point` branch to begin on the tip of the `next` branch, keeping all the original commits of the former (which I squashed into one for simplicity of reading). The benefit of rebasing is a cleaner project history, which makes sense when changing to a monorepo (so it looks like that from start).